# No irreducible subrepresentations

Tags: rt.representation-theory, p-adic-groups, modular-representation-theory

Let $p$ be a prime number. In the paper [The image of Colmez's Montreal functor](https://arxiv.org/abs/1005.2008), on the page 12, the author points out an interesting property: The smooth mod $p$ representation $\mathrm{c-Ind}^{GL_2(\mathbb{Q}_p)}_{GL_2(\mathbb{Z}_p)} \mathbf{1}$ does not contain any irreducible subrepresentation.

**Question** Could you please give an argument why this should be the case?

Comment: It's been a while but I'm interested myself so here is an idea (which probably won't work): we know that irreducible representations of $GL_2(\mathbb{Q}_p)$ admits a central character, does $\text{diag}(p,p)$ acts as a scalar on some nonzero vector here?